# swift saving scrollview content when tab is switched

Tags: swift, xcode

I have tabbed app and I know views get destroyed every time the user goes to a different tab and navigates back. However in on of my tabs I have a scroll view that will contain a bunch of content. I dont want to reload the content every time the user switches tabs and comes back. Is there anyway to save the content in the scroll view so it is automatically displayed once the user comes back to the tab. If there is no way to do this do I have to reload the content of the scroll view everytime?

viewModel:

```
import Foundation

class FeedViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var content = [Feed]()
    
    var conversations: [Feed] {
        return content
    }
```

view:

```
struct JobsView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = FeedViewModel()

                ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing){
                    ScrollView{
                        LazyVStack{
                            ForEach(viewModel.conversations){ content in
                                FeedRowView(content: content)
                                    .padding()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change

```
@ObservedObject var viewModel = FeedViewModel()
```

To

```
@StateObject var viewModel = FeedViewModel()
```

`StateObject` is for initializing and `ObservedObject` is for observing changes on an object whose lifecycle is being managed some other way.

Comment: thanks, im a little new to swift. If I use StateObject for my viewModel how will my scroll view update if my content var is modified, since stateObject is for initializing and not for observing changes to the content var

Comment: @jackmanAhmed it observes too. It is mostly the same as `ObservedObject` with the main difference being that it has the ability to manage lifecycle. `ObservedObject` does not have that ability, objects get recreated unexpectedly as you ar experiencing.

Comment: just another quick question. Do I have to use viewControllers to manage my views? Or can I have my view logic simply in the view. What are the downsides to putting logic in the views. Would I be unable to create an app that doesnt utilize UIKIt and viewControllers?

Comment: @jackmanAhmed No and Yes. No because SwiftUI doesn’t use UIViewControllers directly they belong to UIKit and Yes because SwiftUI is still very limited, you will have to Interface with UIKit at some point.